# iOS: Decryption not supported on key stored in secure enclave

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, keychain

Compiling for iOS 11 (which allegedly solves all the secure enclave related bugs), I'm trying to create a key pair stored in the secure enclave to use for encrypting/decrypting data, but somewhere along the line the key gets corrupted:

```objc
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
NSError *gen_error = nil;

SecAccessControlRef sacObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly, kSecAccessControlBiometryAny, &error);

if (sacObject == NULL || error != NULL) { /* handled */ }

NSDictionary *keyAttributes = @{
    (id)kSecClass: (id)kSecClassKey,
    (id)kSecAttrKeyType: (id)kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,
    (id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: @256,
    (id)kSecAttrTokenID: (id)kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
    (id)kSecAttrIsPermanent: @YES,
    (id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: biometricKeyTag, //static between all calls
    (id)kSecAttrAccessControl: (__bridge_transfer id)sacObject,
};

SecKeyRef privateKey = (__bridge SecKeyRef) CFBridgingRelease(SecKeyCreateRandomKey((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyAttributes, (void *)&gen_error));

if (gen_error != nil || privateKey == nil) { /* handled */ }

SecKeyRef publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey);

Boolean algorithmDSupported = SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(privateKey, kSecKeyOperationTypeDecrypt, kSecKeyAlgorithmECIESEncryptionCofactorX963SHA256AESGCM);
Boolean algorithmESupported = SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(publicKey, kSecKeyOperationTypeEncrypt, kSecKeyAlgorithmECIESEncryptionCofactorX963SHA256AESGCM);
// Returns true for both

// OK so far!

// Now retrieve the key just create to mock up using it later

NSDictionary *query = @{
    (id)kSecClass: (id)kSecClassKey,
    (id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: biometricKeyTag,
    (id)kSecAttrKeyType: (id)kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,
    (id)kSecReturnRef: @YES,
    (id)kSecUseOperationPrompt: @""
};
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&privateKey);

if (status != noErr || privateKey == NULL) { /* handled */ }

publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey);
Boolean algorithmDSupported2 = SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(privateKey, kSecKeyOperationTypeDecrypt, kSecKeyAlgorithmECIESEncryptionCofactorX963SHA256AESGCM);
Boolean algorithmESupported2 = SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(publicKey, kSecKeyOperationTypeEncrypt, kSecKeyAlgorithmECIESEncryptionCofactorX963SHA256AESGCM);
// Encryption on the public key is supported, but algorithmDSupported2 is false – cannot decrypt with the key any more
```

Using the key retrieved with `SecItemCopyMatching` for encryption with `SecKeyCreateEncryptedData` seems to work, but `SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported` on `…TypeDecrypt` returns false for these keys, and attempts to decrypt anyway unsurprisingly crashes the app.

How/why does the key not work after retrieval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved it in the end was

- Changing the SecAccessControl flags to `kSecAccessControlBiometryAny|kSecAccessControlPrivateKeyUsage`
- Changing key type to `kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom`
- Moving the key attributes under the `kSecPrivateKeyAttrs` key

No idea why Apple lets you shoot yourself in the foot and doesn't properly validate key generation parameters.

Comment: Any chance you can share the whole complete code? I'm struggling with this, when I add kSecAccessControlPrivateKeyUsage the key turns null. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any minimal sample code at hand, what I wrote above eventually turned into this: https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics/blob/2d65ea8a72853dc0f1b449c0c0950ec597657c8a/ios/ReactNativeBiometrics.m Specifically, createEncryptionKey to make the keys and encryptData to retrieve them afterwards. Hope that helps.